# Communication between the actual device and the virtual environment during iOS development

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, vagrant, virtualbox

I'm developing for iOS with Flutter.

I created a virtual environment on my Mac using Virtual BOX and Vagrant, and set up a server to process API requests and return results.

Example of API
`localhost:8888/api/result`

The problem is this "localhost".

I built it with Android Studio and checked it with the simulator, and found that I could request localhost:8888/api/result and get the result back, no problem.

However, when I checked on the actual iPhone device, I found that communication was not possible.
I think the cause is in localhost.

I expect that localhost will be the iPhone itself when built on the iPhone.

How should I communicate with the virtual environment on my local device at this time?

I want to make API requests to a virtual environment in my local terminal where I built iOS.

Comment: Please clarify whether your app has the necessary entitlements to operate as a server, and access the local network. That would be helpful for isolating your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It was easy.
All I had to do was edit the Vagrantfile and set the public IP.
Of course, it is in the same local network.
I didn't have to specify the port, just request the API and I was good to go.